# TypeError: str.replace is not a function strange error with vue.js Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I am getting a strange error: `vue-resource.common.js Uncaught TypeError: str.replace is not a function` and it seems to be related to an ajax call I am making to fetch some data:

```
export default {
    data: () => ({
      recipes: []
    }),
    ready() {
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/recipes', { 
        headers: { 
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true 
        }
      }).then((recipes) => {
        this.$set('recipes', recipes)
      })
    }
  };
```

I am new to vue.js and really unsure how to debug this... any pointers would be fantastic.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Try `headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }` instead

Comment: Hey @adeneo - thanks, tried that, but then getting: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Are you making cross-domain calls?  If so, the URI you're requesting must allow remote callers.  See http://enable-cors.org/ for more information.

Comment: Thanks Patrick - the rest api is just on a different port from the port the application... Do I still need to allow remote callers in this instance?

Comment: Yes, you still need to allow remote callers.  It's only when the protocol, host **and** port match that the call is considered to be coming from the "same origin" and not restricted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Summary

This is happening because the value of headers in Vue Resource should be a `string` type, rather than a `boolean`.

---

## Details

I don't actually see this in the Vue Resource documentation, but looking through the source code it's easy to see:

The `set` method of a Header ([see here](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/src/http/headers.js#L32)) calls the `trim` function:

```
set(name, value) {
    this.map[normalizeName(getName(this.map, name) || name)] = [trim(value)];
}
```

`trim` assumes that the value is a string ([see here](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/src/util.js)):

```
export function trim(str) {
    return str ? str.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '') : '';
}
```

## Other notes

As discussed in the comments of the question, the way you are using this header is incorrect. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is something used on the **Response** rather than the request. This is technically unrelated to the error, but is something worth mentioning.

For more information on this header, and other Cross Origin request issues you can read [the MDN docs on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)