# GET request throws error: str.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, http, vuejs2

I am struggling with a VueJS project function supposed to make a GET request on the server. It throws an error while this syntax has always been working so far in the rest of the website.

```
this.existingUsers = this.existingMembers.map(a => a.userId)

console.log(this.existingUsers)

this.usersResource = this.$resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/users', {}, {}, {
    headers: {
        existingUsers: this.existingUsers
    }
})

this.usersResource.get().then(response => {
        // If server answer
        if (response.body.success) {
            // Good request
            console.log('1')
        } else {
            // Wrong request
            console.log('2')
        }
    }, _ => {
        // The server doesn't answer
        console.log('3')
    })
}
```

In this situation, the console prints the expected list of existingUsers, but then throw the following error:

> Error in callback for watcher "existingMembers": "TypeError:
>   str.replace is not a function"

(the code is executed in a watcher for existingUsers).

I have tried to empty the callback to:

```
this.existingUsers = this.existingMembers.map(a => a.userId)
console.log(this.existingUsers)
this.usersResource = this.$resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/users', {}, {}, {
    headers: {
        existingUsers: this.existingUsers
    }
})
this.usersResource.get().then(response => { })
```

But the same error is thrown. Any idea what could the problem be?

Comment: Seems like you are passing an object, a number (...) to something expecting a string somewhere. Inspecting the stack trace can help you find where it comes from.

Comment: Likely caused by the headers.  See the comment to this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114926/typeerror-str-replace-is-not-a-function-strange-error-with-vue-js-ajax-call

Comment: Indeed, the array can't be passed via the headers. I will string it to pass it and reconstruct it on the other side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2) there are no words about the type of value in HTTP headers. But, as far as I know, if you use additional libraries, you can pass only `String` as header value.

And your answer is partly right. But I suggest you to avoid using `.toString` in this case.

Let's imagine the situation when one of `existingMembers` has no `userId`. In this case, you will get in `existingUsers` something like this `["ID00101", undefined, "ID01001"]`. After the execution of `.toString()` function inside header you will get

> headers: {
> existingUsers: "ID00101,,ID01001"
> }

So it will be hard to parse.

**Solution**

I suggest using `JSON.stringify` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

So you can get string like this `"["ID00101",null,"ID01001"]"`

Your code can be transformed to

```
this.existingUsers = this.existingMembers.map(a => a.userId)
console.log(this.existingUsers)
this.usersResource = this.$resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/users', {}, {}, {
    headers: {
        existingUsers: JSON.stringify(this.existingUsers)
    }
})
this.usersResource.get().then(response => { })
```

And then parse it with `JSON.parse` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49594052/3245114 for details about why the error happens with Vue Resource

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw debugging, the headers can't pass an array to the server this way.

I decided to pass the array as a string(

```
this.usersResource = this.$resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/users', {}, {}, {
    headers: {
        existingUsers: this.existingUsers.toString()
    }
)
```

and to reconstruct it on the other side as an array, but there might be other solutions / packages that allow sending directly arrays via HTTP GET requests.